# Pass two parameters by render node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to pass the result of two search by render to the ejs, one variable lists the cities and another the UFs to use in the combobox, but I am not getting, could anyone help?

```
  var listaUfes = function(req,res){
    var connection = app.infra.connectionFactory();
    var ufesDAO = new app.infra.UfesDAO(connection);

    return ufesDAO.lista(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        return res.json(results);        
    });

    connection.end();        
  }   

  var listaCidades = function(req, res) {
    var connection = app.infra.connectionFactory();
    var cidadesDAO = new app.infra.CidadesDAO(connection);            

    return cidadesDAO.lista(function(err, results) { 
       console.log(results);
       return res.json(results);                    
    });        

    connection.end();
  }

  app.get('/cidades', function(req,res) {
    res.format({
        html: function() {
            res.render('cidades/frmcidadelista', {lista:listaCidades, siglas:listaUfes});
        },
        json: function() {
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
  });
```